# Using autolayout self-sizing cell in groupTableView,after reloadData,if I scroll upward,tableview will jump

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

tableview jump because it use the estimated cell Height but not the actural cell height.how to fix it?

I am using a group TableView,Which sectionHeader is a twitter,a cell is a comment in it.

Comment: not getting your point.

Comment: can you explain what jump means?

Comment: I am sorry about delaying.I post a new complete problem description in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43449915/group-tableview-using-self-sizing-section-header-after-reload-if-i-scroll-upward